# Angular/ Firebase - Property 'email' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from './../classes/user';
import { AlertService } from './alert.service';
import { Alert } from './../classes/alert';
import { AlertType } from './../enums/alert-type.enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/Observable/of';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})
export class AuthService {

  public currentUser: Observable<User | null>;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private alertService: AlertService,
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    // TODO fetch the user from the Firebase backend, then set the user(actioned!)
    this.currentUser = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null);
        }
      });
  }
  public signup(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // TODO call Firebase signup function(actioned!)

    return Observable.fromPromise(
      this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {
          const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.db.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
          const updatedUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            photoUrl: 'https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/131/131718.jpg'
          };
          userRef.set(updatedUser);
          return true;
        })
        .catch((err) => false)
    );
    return Observable.of(true);
  }

  public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    // TODO call Firebase login function
    return Observable.of(true);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    // TODO call Firebase logout function
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    this.alertService.alerts.next(new Alert('You have been signed out.'));
  }

}
```

Hi - I was hoping someone could help me with the below - im getting an error as shown in the picture which is a piece of he code where the errors are coming from. im new to angular and Firebase and still learning how these work..

basically - im trying to create a chat app - the code is saying - im creating a user with email and password which will parse an email and password which come from the imports.

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth.service.ts(47,85): error TS2339: Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'.
>   src/app/services/auth.service.ts(49,22): error TS2339: Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'.
>   src/app/services/auth.service.ts(50,25): error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'UserCredential'.
>   src/app/services/auth.service.ts(60,5): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.

Everything is working perfectly except these errors are driving me nuts!!

Comment: You'll have to post your type definition for `UserCredential`. This is a Typescript compilation error, not a runtime error. Also, your `return Observable.of(true)` is unreachable because you're already returning the `Observable.fromPromise()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) doesn't have a `uid` property. My best guess is that you're looking for `user.user.uid`.

Comment: Thank you Frank and Joh - it was looking for user.user.uid - seriously - i couldnt figure this out!! it works fine now. 


          const updatedUser = {
            id: user.user.uid,
            email: user.user.email,
            firstName,
            lastName,
            photoUrl: 'https://avatarfiles.alphacoders.com/131/131718.jpg'
          };
        .......
    );
    // return Observable.of(true);
  }

Comment: It becomes confusing when you call the parameter `user`, which is why I always call it something different (like `credential`, `response` or `authEvent`).

Comment: Lesson learned!! Thank you - very helpful :)